# How to add a route in a scaffold resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used scaffold and I want to add a new routing in resources in routes.rb.

But I want to send the link without the id parameter

I want to access index2.html.erb like fleamarkets_path which accesses index.html.erb.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :fleamarkets do
  member do
    get :index
  end
end
```

**default rake routes**

```
fleamarkets GET    /fleamarkets(.:format)            fleamarkets#index
```

**rake routes**

```
index2_fleamarket GET    /fleamarkets/:id/index2(.:format) fleamarkets#index2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you need to use `collection` instead of `member`:

```
resources :fleamarkets do
  collection do
    get :index2
  end
end
```